# Best way to attach icon left to a text

Tags: html, css, icons

I'm bad with CSS, using bootstrap & now I would like to set an icon just before a

, I'd like to create a "blog" talking about bets and so I have to add the type of sport so I chose to use icons in the list

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG61Y.png)

So I tried to do this simply with  but as you can see it's not good, the list is supposed to make 1 line, not 2, also the icon should be at the left

I tried to deal with ":before" but didn't succeed, also I'd like a good way to do it, for me to change dynamically the icon with PHP (by updating the list)

What is the best way to make it ? Thanks

Comment: Place an `<img>` tag inside a `<div>` container that also holds the text, then use a css rule for all such images inside such div's and let the `float` to the left.

Comment: take a look at my answer if you wish :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flexbox is the way to align things these days. This might help get you started:

```css
ul {list-style:none;}
li {display:flex;align-items: center;}
img {margin-right:10px;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/49/51" />  John Doe</li>
  <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" /> Peter Rabbit</li>
</ul>
```

References:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an another way :

```css
ul {
  list-style: none
}
li {
  position: relative;
  background: url(//dummyimage.com/10x10) no-repeat center left;
  padding-left : 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>John Doe</li>
  <li>Peter Rabbit</li>
</ul>
```