# How to display list of textboxes(price list) while clicking checkbox in css

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs

While changing the supplier and store the item list dynamically populates , while clicking the item user wants to enter the ordered quantity , the question is how can i display the ordered quantity textbox in left to the item checkbox in css

[image: 0]

This is the piece of code for item and ordered quantity:

[image: 0]

How to style this piece of code such that ordered quantity will be left to the item?

Comment: Better to give code example not by screenshots, to [help others reproduce your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your label is inside a div, but your input element is outside the div. Move the closing `</div>` tag to be after the `<input ... />` tag.

As you know, DIVs are containers - like boxes. It is not a bad thing to have tons of containers on your page if they help to organize the page structure.

I suggest adding `display:flex` onto this div:

```
<div key={item.ITEM} style={{display:flex}}>
```

That should put everything onto one line. Note that flexbox only affects the immediate children. Also note that any element can be both a flex-child and a flex-parent at the same time. (*In the below example, note that the flex-child class is not needed - it was added only as a "label" to help the reader*)

```css
.flex-parent{display:flex;}
.flex-child{} /* Not needed */
#red{background:red;}
#green{background:green;}
#blue{background:blue;}
#gold{background:gold;}
#sam{width:100px;justify-content:center;}
div{padding:10px;}
.half{width:50%;}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-parent flex-child" id="red">
    <div class="half flex-child">Bob</div>
    <div class="half flex-child">Sue</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child" id="blue"></div>
  <div class="flex-child" id="green"></div>
  <div class="flex-parent flex-child" id="gold">
    <div class="flex-child" id="sam">Sam</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here are a couple of other answers with good links for learning how to use flexbox (it's really very simple). The video tutorial in the second link is excellent.

[Best way to attach icon left to a text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37503334/best-way-to-attach-icon-left-to-a-text/37503422#37503422)

[How do I center child div in parent and have it fixed to the top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55073663/how-do-i-center-child-div-in-parent-and-have-it-fixed-to-the-top/55073717#55073717)

Comment: ok , I got the ordered quantity at the right of the item , what can i do if there is very big list of items for example

Comment: If would use an IF test... that way, the simple ones are already done. Then, for the case where there is more than one item, write another routine that handles that case. Probably some kind of loop that spits out one "row" `<div key={item.ITEM} style={{display:flex}}>` per item.